# Выполнение действий без ввода sudo

Tags: linux, unix, права

Пользователя, находящегося в sudo группе, постоянно мучит 'Permission denied', нельзя даже папку создать без ввода 'sudo' перед 'mkdir'. Я помню, что это решалось парой каких-то действий по отношению к директории, с которой нужно работать конкретному пользователю или группе. Читать тонны мануалов в поисках одной команды как-то не комильфо, поэтому буду благодарен если кто подскажет те самые команды или как решить проблему другими способами. Используется ubuntu 12.04

з.ы. вопросы этой тематики теперь можно на хэшкод писать, да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chmod (change mode - изменить права доступа для пользователей) или chown (change owner - изменить владельца). Да, писать сюда. rootcode и hashcode объединили. [Статья](http://ubuntulinux.ru/config/recipe/izmenit-prava-na-fajly-ili-papki-v-linux/) по теме.

Comment: спасибо, это оно!

Comment: @fogipoziw, всегда пожалуйста)